# what if two logrotate run concurrently

Tags: linux, cron, logrotate

I know this sounds weird...

I have a project which will run "logrotate myConf.conf" automatically every hour.

Besides, in my cron/, there is also a logrotate running...

The two process might have chance to modify the same log file

In this case what will happen?

Will the log file be totally screwed? or just one of the command will fail? (which is good enough)

Comment: why not create two scripts and run them using `at` command to run at the same time and see what happens, I would think whichever process gets a lock first will run...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there may be issues relating to the state file that `logrotate` keeps.

See my answer to a question about a corrupt state file due to concurrent runs of `logrotate` from cron:

- [/var/lib/logrotate/status gets invalid entries](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/437351/var-lib-logrotate-status-gets-invalid-entries)

The summary: be sure that your specific rotation job is either run as part of the system's ordinary rotation job, or run it from a personal cron job and use a separate state file (specified with the `-s` option to `logrotate`). I either case, only run the rotation from one cron job.