# /var/lib/logrotate/status gets invalid entries

Tags: cron, logrotate

We are seeing our  `/var/lib/logrotate/status` gets invalid entries like following:

```
saurabh@1236:~$ cat /var/lib/logrotate/status
logrotate state -- version 2
"/var/log/syslog" 2018-3-13
"/var/log/auth.log" 2018-3-13
"/var/log/debug" 2018-3-13
"/var/log/lpr.log" 2018-3-13
"/var/log/user.log" 2018-3-13
"/var/log/mail.info" 2018-3-13
"/var/log/cron.log" 2018-3-13
og/messages" 2018-3-13           <=== Corrupted entry
"/var/log/cron.log" 2018-3-13
"/var/log/messages" 2018-3-13
```

Not sure how this gets corrupted in this way. It happens randomly after 10/12 days.

My guess is may be this is because of multiple crons editing this file, which is causing this issue as multiple trying to edit this file, but I am not sure that might be the issue. To test that I have added some random delay in one of recent cron added like this:

```
*/10 * * * * root sleep $(expr $RANDOM \% 90); /usr/sbin/logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/myFile
```

Any better suggestion for an concrete solution?

Comment: Is there another cron job that executes `logrotate`?  Have a look in the various `/etc/cron.*` directories as well.

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, there are other cronjobs as well which uses `logrotate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple concurrent instances of `logrotate` being run by cron jobs on your machine.  There is no locking on the state file used, and so the different `logrotate` jobs "step on each other's toes" when updating it.

Since you added your `myFile` configuration for `logrotate` in the `/etc/logrotate.d` directory, you don't have to explicitly rotate them in a separate cron job.  The usual `logrotate` cron job run would pick up that configuration automatically.

If you *need* to run the rotation more often than what the system's default log rotation happens, I'd recommend putting the `myFile` configuration elsewhere.

To ensure that your rotation job does not use the same state file (in the instances when the rotation job may run at the same time as the system's log rotation job), use another state file:

```
/usr/sbin/logrotate -f -s /some/location/myFile.state /some/location/myFile
```

Note that the job does not need to run as root unless the logfiles are owned by root or some user other than yourself. In other words, if the logfiles belong to you, you may do the rotation in a personal cron job.